# VisualWorks - Find characters in string and replace them

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I have one word. At first, instead of letters, there are only ?. So for example, word 'town' would be shown like this '????'.
Then user guesses letter and if he nails it, it changes from ? to actual letter.
For example, if he guesses t, it would look like this 't???'.

The problem is, that I have no idea, how to go through string and divide it to characters. And if I somehow do it, I cannot change it in the new string.

Should look somehow like this.

```
word do: [ :c | 
          c = guessedChar
                ifTrue[mask := mask, guessedChar]
                ifFalse[mask := mask, '?']
            ].
```

`mask` is initialized to nil, because the `word` length can change and `word` is `String`.
`guessedChar` is connected to inputField, however it contains only one character at a time.

And would it be better, do it once for every guessedChar or hold collection of all guessed characters and run it over every time?

Answer (score 2):

A `String` is a `Collection` of `Character` objects. So you can use the same methods that apply to other collections, too (like `#select:`, `#collect:` or `#reject:`)

```
guessedCharacters := 'ts'.
mask := word collect:[:each | (guessedCharacters includes: each)
                                 ifTrue:[each]
                                 ifFalse:[$?]].
```

Please note that `'t'` is a `String` with the `Character` t. A `Character` can be written with `$` prefix as literal character `$t`.

As `String` is a subclass of `SequenceableCollection` you can concatenate two Strings via `,`. You cannot however concatenate a `String` and a `Character`.

Instead you could use `#copyWith:` to append a `Character` to a `String`. The result is a new `String`, it wouldn't modify the existing instance.

Comment: This one also works, and it is much more clearer. However still, when new guessedChar comes in, it forgots the previous one. How to make it so it remembers all guessed characters?

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit of what you try to achieve in order for us to make better suggestions. From your other comments I think `guessedChar` is a `ValueHolder` that is connected to an input field? It appears to contain a `String` and not just a `Character`. So you already have a list of characters that you can test against.

Comment: guessedChar is connected to input field, but it contains only `Character` because you cannot put more than one character into it. But yeah, when user gives new character, I have to test it against the old and the new one. I thought it could work without list, just adding one character at time

Comment: don't implement your code using "can I write it without x". Write your code so that it's easy to understand. You can look at your old code and ask yourself: do i still understand everything i've written here? If not, why not. If you think your implementation is too complicated (but working!) try to clean it up then, but not before you got it working in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `Character` in the input field? As far as i can tell, you cannot choose `Character` as type, only `String`. Even if you manage to limit its size to 1, it's still a `String`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's String, but the size is limited to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
word doWithIndex: [:c :i | c = guess ifTrue: [mask at: i put: c]]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
i := 1.
word do: [:c |
  c = guess ifTrue: [mask at: i put: c].
  i := i + 1]
```

except that you don't have to initialize and increment `i` (which is a little bit more error prone, and more verbose)

---

**Addendum**

Given that instances of `String` cannot grow or change their size, which is immutable, I assume that what might change is the variable `word`. In that case you should initialize `mask` accordingly, so both strings keep always the same length. Like this:

```
 word: aString
   word := aString.
   mask := word copy atAllPut: $?
```

If you also want to preserve the characters already guessed:

```
 word: aString
   | guessed |
   word := aString.
   guessed := mask reject: [:c | c = $?].
   mask := word copy atAllPut: $?.
   guessed do: [:c | self try: c].
```

Where `#try:` is the method we had before

```
try: aCharacter
  word doWithIndex: [:c :i | c = aCharacter ifTrue: [mask at: i put: c]]
```

(you may want to `uppercase` things if required)

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't quite work. It gives me "an UserMessage('Strings only store Characters', #errStoreCharacters, #dialogs)". I used "guessedChar value asUppercase" instead of "guess" and doWithIndex, because there is no withIndexDo in VW, but everything else is same

Comment: Now I have this code `word doWithIndex: [:c :i | c = guessedChar value asUppercase
  ifTrue: [mask at: i put: c]
  ifFalse: [mask:= mask, '?']].`    but it does not change when the character is guessed correctly

Comment: I've modified my answer to use `doWithIndex:` instead. Note also that my code assumes that `word` is a `String`. If is not, then the block argument `c` will not be a `Character`. What is `word` in your case?

Comment: If `mask` has been initialized to all `?`, you shouldn't need to do anything when the `guess` doesn't match. What are you trying to do in that case?

Comment: It is defined like this `word := 'town' asUppercase.` so it should be String

Comment: `mask` is initialized to nil, because the word length is changing

Comment: Ah, ok. Then, please include that in the question and clarify further what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Done. But why are the changes not displaying properly?

Comment: Yeah, finally it works. It have one minor flaw though. If I do this line `guessed := mask reject: [:c | c = $?].` it shows the word without any `?`. If I erase it, it works, but do not preserve the previous characters found.

Answer (score 0):

```
"initially"
actualWord := 'phlebotomy'.
actualMask := actualWord collect: [:ch| $?].

"after each guess"
word := actualWord readStream.
mask := actualMask readStream.
newMask := WriteStream on: String new.
[ word atEnd
] whileFalse:
    [ nextCh := word next = guessedCharcter
                  ifTrue: [mask skip. guessedCharacter]
                  ifFalse: [mask next].
      newMask nextPut: nextCh
    ].
actualMask := newMask contents
```